# Is it possible to get Brunch to display more information on compile errors

Tags: sass, brunch

Currently brunch.io running with watch just displays a very generic error message for me:

> 02 Dec 11:45:42 - error: Compiling of app/brunch/styles/public.scss failed.

I am trying to migrate over a bunch of legacy sass and Would love to know what/where it is breaking on, but I couldn't find anything to expand on this error message in the config documentation.

Anyone know a way to get brunch to display more detailed error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in sass-brunch as of version 2.9.0

https://github.com/brunch/sass-brunch/issues/123#issuecomment-267175829